# How to addAttachment on Camel 3.0

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-camel-mail

in Camel 2.x I could add an Attachment to a Message like:

```
exchange.getOut().addAttachment("LogFile.log.gz", new DataHandler(Base64.decodeBase64(FileContentBase64),"application/x-gzip"));
```

But in Camel 3.0 it is not possible. I change my code like the migration guide says:

```
exchange.getMessage().addAttachment("LogFile.log.gz", new DataHandler(Base64.decodeBase64(FileContentBase64),"application/x-gzip"));
```

But it is not working. Also this not:

```
exchange.getIn().addAttachment("LogFile.log.gz", new DataHandler(Base64.decodeBase64(FileContentBase64),"application/x-gzip"));
```

Have someone an idea, to solve this.

I want to e-Mail this Attachment.

Comment: Do you get any compilation or runtime error? Please add it to the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Camel **Version 3** was modularized a lot. So the **attachments API** was extracted and has to be used differently, see [Camel 3 Migration Guide](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html#_attachments_api_on_message):

> The attachments API (javax.activation) has been moved out of `org.apache.camel.message` into an extension `org.apache.camel.attachment.AttachmentMessage` from the **camel-attachments** JAR.
>
> To use this API you can get it via the `getMessage` method on Exchange:
>
> ```java
> AttachmentMessage am = exchange.getMessage(AttachmentMessage.class); am.addAttachment("myAtt", new DataHandler(...));
> ```

Comment: More info on the new [Attachments Component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/attachments.html)